# Is there any SharePoint Control to open document library in browser popup

Tags: document-library, user-controls, popup

I'm trying to  open document library in browser popup window so user can select document from it.

Is is possible to open library in Popup window?

Is there any SharePoint control to open document library in Popup window.

Answer (score 1):

```
SP.UI.ModalDialog.showModalDialog({ 
            url: "URL of Library", 
            title: "Title of page", 
            allowMaximize: true, 
            showClose: true, 
            width: 850, 
            height: 600, 
            dialogReturnValueCallback: newCallback 
        });
function newCallback(dialogResult, returnValue) { 
   SP.UI.ModalDialog.RefreshPage(SP.UI.DialogResult.OK); 
}
```

This should open you library in pop-up.

Comment: what would be the URL ?? it's like https://MyServer/sites/appdev/MyLibrary/Forms/AllItems.aspx